# Can you create a react component in JSX where the component comes from a passed down property?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have several routes that that render the same component.  Each route has a specific component as a property that it will render.

```
<CommonComponent specificComponent={SpecificComponent} propName="propValue" />
```

This works as expected within CommonComponent:

```
React.createElement(specificComponent, { dataUrl: dataUrl });
```

Is there a JSX way to do the React.createElement?  A sample route looks like this:

```
<Route path="/pageOne">
    <CommonComponent specificComponent={SpecificComponentOne} dataUrl="dataUrl" />
</Route>
<Route path="/pageTwo">
    <CommonComponent specificComponent={SpecificComponentTwo} dataUrl="dataUrl" />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. The required trick is to store the component in a variable with a capitalized name! Sounds silly, but it's true. So in `CommonComponent` you can just use:

```js
const ComponentToRender = props.specificComponent;
return (<ComponentToRender ... />);
```